# How to setup buttons with "imBack" type in Slack channel using ms bot builder

Tags: c#, botframework, slack-api

I've developed few bots using ms botbuilder, there was no problems with Buttons with "imBack" type on Skype, FB, Telegram and web chat. 
However trying to make it work on Slack i found (and seems like its not documented) that you need extra configuring of Interactive Messages in APP admin panel. So here's my questions regarding this issue:

1. is it true that its the only way?
2. If so what's the real reason for that, everything works just fine in all   other channels.
3. Is there a way to setup it programmatically, cos it will be real bad for distribution of bot?
4. even when i setup endpoint in admin panel looks like it makes request that is barely compatible with how ms builder works (it sends some GET where we need post with relevant info)

Code sample:

```
...
var reply = activity.CreateReply("hi, can i ask you few question?");

reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>(){};
var buttonSelect = new CardAction
{
    Value = $" /startCommand",
    Type = "imBack",
    Title = "ok, ask me"
};

var cardForButton = new ThumbnailCard { Buttons = new List<CardAction> { buttonSelect } };
reply.Attachments.Add(cardForButton.ToAttachment());

await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botaccount, userAccount, reply);
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually all needed to be done is put https://slack.botframework.com/api/Actions in Request URL when enabling Interactive Messages in Slack, not sure that it was documented earlier on Ms bot framework panel, but it is now. Issue resolved.

Comment: Yes, it works for me. Thanks. However when i click one button, both button animates. Any idea, why?

Comment: @Snekithan what exactly you mean by "anumates" ? Can you show?

Comment: I mean mouse click animation. It returns correct button click value, but it renders as all the buttons are clicked.

Comment: i think it's issue of slack client, don't think it relative to bot framework, you should write to slack support.

Answer (score 1):

2 things you can try that are possible solutions

1. You probably did, but did you activate interactive messages in your slack api dashboard?
2. There is a token (Verification Token)  that you need to get from the oauth section of the Slack api site for your app.  you need to include that with the other information here https://slack.botframework.com/Dev/?botId={yourBotID}

Comment: Yes i configured interactive messages (put https://myappadress.com/api/messages in Request URL field) , though i didn't get the 2nd point. I found OAuth Access Token, but where i need to pass it?

Comment: on dev.botframework.com if you have already added the slack channel, click on edit.  In the "Submit your credentials" section, there is a verification token field.

Comment: i have a same problem. It renders buttons, upon clicking, no value send back to bot.